# MFC WaitForSingleObject and CCriticalSection - how to use?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mfc, locking

I'm currently diving into a legacy code base that makes heavy use of MFC classes. It uses `CCriticalSection` as mutex, and `WaitForSingleObject` to 'lock' that mutex. The code roughly looks like this:

```
struct Foo {
  static CCriticalSection mutex;

  void doSomeWriting() {
     mutex.Lock();
     …
     mutex.Unlock();
  }

  void doSomeReading() {
     WaitForSingleObject(mutex, some_timeout);
     …
     // No unlocking here!
  }
};
```

I would provide a MWE, but a minimal application using MFC seems to be several thousand lines of code, if my Visual Studio is to be trusted.

I'm currently running the application under the [Application Verifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/win7appqual/application-verifier), which flags the `WaitForSingleObject()` call and complains about a handle inside `mutex` being NULL.

I know that I [should just banish CCriticalSection](http://www.flounder.com/avoid_mfc_syncrhonization.htm) from the code (and in fact we're in the process of refactoring this to use `std::recursive_mutex`), but I would like to at least have an idea what the original author wanted to achieve with this.

Unfortunately, I cannot find documentation on how `WaitForSingleObject` and `CCriticalSection` interact. The [CCriticalSection docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccriticalsection-class?view=msvc-160) don't mention `WaitForSingleObject` at all, and the [WaitForSingleObject docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) do not mention `CCriticalSection`. The [example for using critical sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-critical-section-objects) only handles `CRITICAL_SECTION` objects, which apparently need to somehow be initialized. Also, `WaitForSingleObject` is not used in these examples.

### My Questions

- Is calling `WaitForSingleObject` on a `CCriticalSection` even allowed?
- Is it necessary to somehow initialize a `CCriticalSection` before calling `WaitForSingleObject` on it? The Application Verifier error seems to indicate this.
- Does `WaitForSingleObject` lock the `CCriticalSection`? Or does it just block until the critical section is unlocked?
- If it locks: Wouldn't the `doSomeReading()` method in my example need to unlock the critical section again?
- If it does not do locking: Then the example above does not guarantee that `doSomeWriting()` isn't started in thread A while thread B is busy executing `doSomeReading()` (after the `WaitForSingleObject()` call), right?

Comment: MFC documentation for CCriticalSection says if you need timed waits, then use a CMutex instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccriticalsection-class?view=msvc-160#ccriticalsection

Comment: Yes, I guess that's because `CCriticalSection::Lock()` does not accept a timeout. But the original author used `WaitForSingleObject` instead of using `Lock()`. Is that supported? I would use neither and just go with STL methods, but I'm trying to understand what the original author intended here…

Comment: According to the docs, the original author was wrong...or maybe MFC changed some from when he wrote it. ISTM, if you want to WaitForSingleObject(), then you can't use CCriticalSection--according to the docs. I can't dive deeper than that right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Application Verifier [...] flags the `WaitForSingleObject()` call and complains about a handle inside mutex being `NULL`.

Application Verifier is correct. That's exactly what's happening. It's pretty obvious, too, why this is happening. It's far less obvious, why Microsoft decided that it were a good idea to force [CCriticalSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccriticalsection-class) into the [CSyncObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/csyncobject-class) class hierarchy.

Let's start with the base class, `CSyncObject` which looks like this (with everything not immediately related to the issue stripped):

```cpp
struct CSyncObject {
    CSyncObject() : m_hObject{nullptr} {}
    operator HANDLE() const { return m_hObject; }
    HANDLE m_hObject;
}
```

There's a default c'tor that initializes the only data member (`m_hObject`), and a conversion operator (`operator HANDLE()`) so that objects of type `CSyncObject` can be passed to functions that expect an argument of type `HANDLE` (like `WaitForSingleObject`).

Other than the data member being public, this is really just a pretty standard wrapper around a native Windows synchronization primitive represented as a `HANDLE`. Things start to go sideways when we take a look at `CCriticalSection`:

```cpp
struct CCriticalSection : CSyncObject {  // <- Look ma, I'm a CSyncObject!
    CCriticalSection() { /* Initialize m_sect */ }
    operator CRITICAL_SECTION*() { return &m_sect; }
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_sect;
}
```

Again, a public data member, gotta appreciate the consistency anyway. But look, there's more! `CCriticalSection` inherits from `CSyncObject`, so now it has an `m_hObject`, too. Which, as you might have guessed, it never touches, reads from, or changes to anything other than the base class' c'tor initialized it to (there's your `NULL` that Application Verifier told you about).

This wouldn't be all *that* bad, if `CCriticalSection` didn't also inherit the public `operator HANDLE()`. With that a `CCriticalSection` can now be used anywhere a `HANDLE` is expected. Like, say, `WaitForSingleObject`.

With all that in place, `WaitForSingleObject(mutex, some_timeout)` compiles, and even runs without immediately failing. Sure, it fails parameter validation, but when you aren't checking the return value... What it boils down to is just a very verbose no-op. It certainly doesn't wait for anything, or guard against concurrent execution. It needs to be fixed.

The remaining questions:

> Is calling `WaitForSingleObject` on a `CCriticalSection` even allowed?

Sure, as we've seen. `CCriticalSection` pretends hard enough to be a `CSyncObject` so that the compiler won't mind.

> Is it necessary to somehow initialize a `CCriticalSection` before calling `WaitForSingleObject` on it? The Application Verifier error seems to indicate this.

Yes. Critical sections need to be initialized with [InitializeCriticalSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsection) or [InitializeCriticalSectionAndSpinCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-initializecriticalsectionandspincount). That doesn't make a `CRITICAL_SECTION` a legal argument to `WaitForSingleObject`.

> Does `WaitForSingleObject` lock the `CCriticalSection`? Or does it just block until the critical section is unlocked?

No, but [EnterCriticalSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-entercriticalsection) will take ownership, that's released with a call to [LeaveCriticalSection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-leavecriticalsection).

> If it locks: Wouldn't the `doSomeReading()` method in my example need to unlock the critical section again?

It would, if it used the correct API call to take ownership. Since it doesn't do anything, there's no need to release anything either.

> If it does not do locking: Then the example above does not guarantee that `doSomeWriting()` isn't started in thread A while thread B is busy executing `doSomeReading()` (after the `WaitForSingleObject()` call), right?

Correct. Thread A and B can enter `doSomeWriting()` concurrently. There isn't any synchronization implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The answers submitted by the other members cover your questions well. In summary:

- Calling `WaitForSingleObject()` for a `CCriticalSection` object is wrong, because a critical section is not a waitable object, although in MFC it inherits from `CSyncObject`. Critical sections provide exclusive/serialized access to a section of code, for the threads of the same process (just like the Mutex objects, but with the above limitation - and they are more efficient too). The only valid operations with critical sections are Enter/Leave (Lock/Unlock).
- Win32 Critical sections need to be initialized, but the `CCriticalSection` class constructor (which is just a wrapper of it) does this for you.
- `WaitForSingleObject()` won't lock a critical section, the only way to lock a critical section is a call to `EnterCriticalSection()` (Win32) or `CCriticalSection::Lock()` (MFC) - no timeout in both cases.
- Since that `WaitForSingleObject()` call doesn't really wait or lock anything (it's just erroneous use here), yes, the critical section in `doSomeWriting()` can be entered in thread A while thread B is busy executing `doSomeReading()`. But no two threads can enter the critical section in `doSomeWriting()` concurrently.

I think what the author was trying to achieve is synchronized access to a shared resource(s), in the following manner:

- Only one writer at a time.
- Multiple concurrent readers, while no writing is taking place.

The latter would supposedly be achieved by the `WaitForSingleObject()` call, but this was obviously a misconception.

As has been pointed-out in the links you provided, MFC's `CSyncObject`-derived objects have their own problems, so you need an alternative implementation.

You could use the Win32 Synchronization objects. [Critical Sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/critical-section-objects) objects are actually re-entrant (although I don't think this is useful at all). They can also be used in combination with [Condition Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/condition-variables). You could use such an implementation to prevent writers updating the shared resource while readers work, along with a (Manual-reset) [Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) object (set/cleared by the writer), to keep readers from accessing the resource while writing takes place (what the `WaitForSingleObject()` call was supposed to do).

However, although I admit I have never actually tried this mechanism, I think what suits most (I would dare to say exactly) what you want to achieve, are the [Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks). They provide synchronization for reading and writing, implementing that "Single Writer - Multiple Readers" functionality through the use of a single object. You could encapsulate these calls in a C++ class, but I see little benefit in this if at all, as the Win32 implementation is quite "high-level" already, and the calls would be 1:1. Take a look in the documentation.

Comment: *"encapsulate these calls in a C++ class, but I see little benefit in this if at all"* - C++ has destructors and access control. Together with move semantics that allows to you **automatically** manage resources. That's HUGE. I suppose that decades of OOP have crippled our ability to clearly see what C++ features truly provide value.

Comment: @IInspectable Indeed, C++ does offer all these, but I was referring specifically to the SRW API, which is so simple that there is no need for a wrapper - all one needs is a `PSRWLOCK` variable. I really see no benefit in replacing a call like `AcquireSRWLockShared(&srw)` with say `srw.LockShared()` - there is no handle to relese either. In the above code (`Foo` structure and functions) those `Lock()/Unlock()/WaitForSingleObject()` calls could simply be replaced with SRW calls in-place - it's just 5 lines of code. It would require much more code to define a class, which would be used only once.

Comment: Placing [ReleaseSRWLockExclusive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasesrwlockexclusive) or [ReleaseSRWLockShared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-releasesrwlockshared) in a destructor, though, suddenly makes your code exception safe. There's benefit in that, like, say, correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but in response to your

> minimal application using MFC seems to be several thousand lines of code

Here it is:

```
#include <afxmt.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

struct Foo {
    static CCriticalSection mutex;

    void doSomeWriting() {
        mutex.Lock();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        mutex.Unlock();
    }

    void doSomeReading() {
        WaitForSingleObject(mutex, 1000);
        //…
        // No unlocking here!
    }
};
CCriticalSection Foo::mutex;

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    std::thread t = std::thread(&Foo::doSomeWriting, f);
    f.doSomeReading();
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I couldn't figure out what headers needed to be included (the Microsoft documentation helpfully does not mention the necessary headers…), so I just created a blank MFC project in VS - and that's huge.